# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query Exception while executing this code

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

`

Hi, I am getting above Exception while executing this function.Here i am trying to fetch distinct of  a particular column. Please help me solve this issue...`.Thanks in advance.

```
public List<Object[]> findDistinctProductBrand(){
    SQLQuery squery =null;
    try{
        Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        squery =(SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery("select distinct product_brand from ecm_product").addEntity(EcmProduct.class).list();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in ProductDaoImpl inside findDistinctproductBrand "+e);
    }
    return squery.list();
}
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Transformers in ur code . give it a Try:

```
String sql = "select distinct product_brand from ecm_product";
//or     String sql = "select distinct(product_brand) from ecm_product";//no difference actually
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List results = query.list();
```

and you may follow [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm)

Let me know if it works.